# What is this type of screw head for accepting test hooks connection called?

Tags: identification, screw-terminal

These screw heads are useful for retaining electrical connection with test hooks because of the two collars. What are these type of screws called?

[image: Screw heads shown attached to electrical test hooks.]
[image: Screw head with multiple collars.]

Comment: Hooks ? for an RF connection?  I guess for  DC that's OK.

Comment: @SunnyskyguyEE75 Yes you are right, these "turret terminals" are only used for the DC voltage supply for these Mini-Circuit devices. The RF input and outputs are through the other more identifiable BNC or SMA connections.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a *turret terminal*.

Surprisingly, the only other question I can remember about this kind of part was asked just [yesterday](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/426543/what-are-turret-connectors).

Comment: Wow, it's odd that someone else would ask what they were called, knowing what they're for, the day after I asked what they're for, knowing what they're called!