# Name of a connector

Tags: components

I've been trying to find a suitable Vcc and ground connector for my DIY RF amplifier, however, after some days of searching I haven't been really able to track them down.

Could anyone perhaps identify the name of the Vcc and ground connectors in the picture attached?

The closest I got to are heremtic RF feedthroughs and Mill-Max terminals, but haven't found identical ones.

Thanks[image]

Comment: The ground terminal is called a "turret terminal", and is intended to have a wire soldered to it.  I would probably solder to the other terminal as well.

Comment: The other connecter is generally referred to as an emi feedthrough, and generally acts as a lowpass filter, filtering out noise on the DC supply line.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What are turret connectors?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/426543/what-are-turret-connectors)